# How the amount of memory is determined in C++?

Tags: c++, memory

I am interested to find out what is the memory limit for the automatic and dynamically-allocated variables, so I tested things like that:

```
int main() {
    const int N = 1000000;
    int a[N];
    a[1] = 100;
}
```

I found the maximum N that would not incur a Segmentation fault is 2,600,000, about 10MB.

Then I tested dynamically allocated variables, like this:

```
int main() {
    const int N = 1000000;
    int* a = new int [N];
    delete[] a;
}
```

I found that maximum N that would not throw an exception is about 730,000,000, that's about 3GB.

Now the question is, how is the 10MB limit (for automatic variables) and 3GB limit (for dynamically-allocated variables) determined. I assume it is related to my machine? Also, is there any way to increase the limit, in case I really need it?

Comment: 3G is fairly typical limit for a process on a 32bit cpu, the other 1G being reserved for hardware addressing, the OS, etc...

Comment: @BenVoigt, I did see discussion about 3GB, but I don't any discussion about 10MB, that's why I asked it as one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit for automatic variables is the amount of memory allocated for the machine stack. 10MB is actually rather high; 1 or 2 MB is a more common default.

Obviously, the 3GB is the OS limit -- it's roughly the size of the process space allowed by the OS to a program. It'll vary widely by OS and hardware platform.

Comment: Do you know where the limit for automatic variable is specified? Or how I can find out directly instead of testing?

Comment: `ulimit -s` should tell you how many bytes you can allocate on the stack.

Comment: @mange : of course, `ulimit` works less well on some OSs than on others :) @JohnYang: On Windows, the value is set for a given executable with the `/STACK` linker option.

Comment: @mange Great! That is the answer I am looking for. Do you know how to change it on linux?

Comment: `ulimit -s NUM` will change the limit in bash. Note that it will only change it for that bash session, however (so all other bash sessions are unaffected). Also: above I meant to say kbytes, not bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Language mandates nothing. It's all implementation-defined.

Automatic variables usually go onto stack, and you can usually increase the maximum size via compiler options. Free store is usually heap, and is limited only by usable address space. Don't count on more than 2-3GB in 32-bit environment, the limit will be much higher in 64-bit environment. Of course, you won't be able to allocate all of the 64-bit address space, you'll hit the limit of available virtual memory (RAM + swap space).

Answer (score 0):

The 3 GB limit can probably be fixed by moving to a 64-bit OS (with plenty of RAM).

There's a reasonable chance (but no certainty) that the 10 MB limit can be adjusted with some linker flags.

Comment: A 32-bit application can use a 3GB viewport into a much  larger memory region, using the memory-mapped file API.